# Git revert giving both modified conflict

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

In my existing repo, i made a file new.txt for POC purpose.
I added the text 'commit 1' to it, added it and committed it with message '1' and pushed onto master on origin.
Then I added the text 'commit 2' to the text file, added it and committed it with message '2' and pushed onto master on origin.
Then I added the text 'commit 3' to the text file, added it and committed it with message '3' and pushed onto master on origin.

My **git log** at this point showed this

commit 4589b94ecb6b19a8ecf3b1913fe51d5f6b0aca79
Author: shubham 
Date:   Thu Aug 31 13:57:51 2017 +0530

```
3
```

commit 4b3f99bc6c36a6c409af7392d5b7bee6362cfdd1
Author: shubham 
Date:   Thu Aug 31 13:57:29 2017 +0530

```
2
```

commit 8ad49853d12863ab48f28d741b97490036e35533
Author: shubham 
Date:   Thu Aug 31 13:57:09 2017 +0530

```
1
```

commit 236094a2fe5886e1fad16ee785ee2a625d38a651
Author: shubham 
Date:   Fri Jul 14 16:01:33 2017 +0530

```
initial commit added rest services sample classes
```

and the **git status** shows

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
You are currently reverting commit 4b3f99b.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working directory clean.

Now i want to undo the second commit '2'. So i tried **git revert 4b3f9**. This gave an error
error: could not revert 4b3f99b... 2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add ' or 'git rm '
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

I checked **git status** after this and its changed for some reason
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
You are currently reverting commit 4b3f99b.
  (fix conflicts and run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
  (use "git add ..." to mark resolution)

```
both modified:   new.txt
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I don't understand what both modified means and how should i go about undoing a specific commit from a series of commits?

Comment: The modifications to the file that followed the commit you are trying to revert are too close/on top of the modifications you're trying to revert, hence git is asking you to resolve the conflict manually.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen How close would be too close for it to give this kind of error?

Comment: I don't know what threshold the merge algorithm uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is reverting `4b3f99` now.

Since there is conflict for `new.txt` when reverting, you should modify the `new.txt` and finish the revert:

```
# modify and save the new.txt
git add .
git revert --continue
```

Now you finish the convert `4b399f`.